# Render OPTIX on T4 GPU

Tags: python, rendering, gpu

T4 GPU is an RTX GPU, in the nvidia documentation it supposed to support OPTIX.
But when I try to render using OPTIX on that GPU, blender renders on CPU.
I tried to retrieve all available GPUs and what I get is only CPU and CUDA.
Is there a way to enable OPTIX on T4?

Comment: If the GPU is properly detected as CUDA device by Blender in *Edit > Preferences > System*, then it seems the check in `device_optix_info` ([device_optix.cpp](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/device/device_optix.cpp)) fails somehow. Not sure why this would happen though, since the compute capability of the GPU should be high enough. Make sure that you're using a recent graphics driver version.

Comment: It's NVIDIA Driver Version: 450.51.06, CUDA Version: 11.0. Just as stated, this should work but doesn't.

Comment: You may want to ask about this on [DevTalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/) or [blender.chat](https://blender.chat/home) where you can get in contact with the developers involved in the Cycles development.